Group rows within a \pgfplotstable environment by changing the line widths of cell borders
I would like to group rows within my \pgfplotstable environment. In this context, a group is defined to have the same content in column "Type".
Let's say, I have a sorted list like this:
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
   Type,Description
   typA,some text
   typA,some text
   typB,some text
   typC,some text
   typC,some text
   typC,some text
   typD,some text
   typD,some text
\end{filecontents}

I would like to draw a bold border around the first two rows, the third row, the 4th til 6th rows and 7th til 8th rows. But this file content is just an example and will be dynamic in my real environment.
MWE
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\thinLine}{0.1mm}%
\newcommand{\thickLine}{0.5mm}%
\newcommand{\lineWidth}{\thinLine}%

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
   Type,Description
   typA,some text
   typA,some text
   typB,some text
   typC,some text
   typC,some text
   typC,some text
   typD,some text
   typD,some text
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}

\pgfplotstableset{
   verb string type,
   every head row/.append style={
      before row={\hline\rowcolor{gray}},
      after row={\hline}
   },
   after row={
      \specialrule{\expanded{\lineWidth}}{0mm}{0mm}
   },
   every column/.style={
       assign cell content/.code={
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablerow}{5}}{
             \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\lineWidth\expandafter{\thickLine}
          }{
             \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\lineWidth\expandafter{\thinLine}
          }
       },
   },
   columns/Type/.style={
      column type=|c|,
   },
   columns/Description/.style={
      column type=c|,
   },
}

\begin{document}
   \pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}
\end{document}

OUTPUT

EXPECTED OUTPUT


Phew, I understand that you want to work with pgfplotstable. But with so many different line and width styles (some don't seem to be systematic), you might want to consider a TikZ-matrix (or maybe tcolobox).

@cis Probably you are right, I found a better way now as shown in the answer :)

As mentioned in the comments, it doesn't seem to be very suitable to sort the rows as requested in my question.
Therefore I searched for another way how to achieve this and found the following solution:
MWE
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\lastType}{}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
   Type,Description
   typA,some text
   typA,some text
   typB,some text
   typC,some text
   typC,some text
   typC,some text
   typD,some text
   typD,some text
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}

\pgfplotstableset{
   verb string type,
   every head row/.append style={
      before row={\hline\rowcolor{gray}},
      after row={\hline}
   },
   after row={
      \hline
   },
   every column/.style={
       assign cell content/.code={
           \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablecol}{0}}{
               \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Type}\of{\csvdata}
               \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{\lastType}}{
                   \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{$\uparrow$}
               }{
                   \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\lastType\expandafter{\pgfplotsretval}
               }
           }{}
       },
   },
   columns/Type/.style={
      column type=|c|,
   },
   columns/Description/.style={
      column type=c|,
   },
}

\begin{document}
   \pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}
\end{document}

OUTPUT

I think this solution also groups the rows and is still very structured.
